# VLC media player video scaling issue

Tags: vlc-media-player

When I play a video in VLC, by default in window mode it fits to screen, and when I double-click to full-screen video, the border disappears and it becomes completely full-screen.  When I double-click again, the border appears again.  So far so good.

What I want is when I play a video in window mode, the video stays at its original resolution, and when I double-click in full-screen, it becomes fit-to-screen size.  When I double-click again, it should shrink to original size.

The only option I found is this **(`video > always fit window`)**.  By unchecking this option, the video resizes to original video size.  But the problem is when I double-click in full-screen, when the border disappears, it still stays at original size.  So I have to choose always fit-to-screen or always watch the video in original size.

**Is there any way to achieve video at original size in window, and fit-to-screen at full-screen?**